# Get percentages from MySQL with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like:

```
schoolId | string1 | string2
   1     |  yes    | no
   1     |  no     | yes
   1     |  null   | yes
   1     |  yes    | no
```

I'm trying to get a result table like:

```
value | string1 | string2
yes   |   50%   |  50%
no    |   25%   |  50%
null  |   25%   |  0%
```

I've put together this so far:

```
select (table.string1/string1_sum)*100 as 'string1 %'
from table , (SELECT SUM(string1) string1_sum FROM table) as t
where schoolId = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give you the `count` and `total` for each value present in string1 and string2:

```
SELECT a.value, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE ifnull(string1, 'null') = a.value AND schoolid = 1) AS s1,
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE ifnull(string2, 'null') = a.value AND schoolid = 1) AS s2,
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1) AS total
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(string1, 'null') AS value FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(string2, 'null') AS value FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1) a
```

Based on these values, you can calculate `percentage` in your application.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6e26d/12/0)**.

**Update**

To calculate the counts in query itself, you can wrap the above query into another one and perform the division:

```
SELECT b.value, (b.s1/b.total)*100 AS string1, (b.s2/b.total)*100 AS string2
FROM (
SELECT a.value, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE ifnull(string1, 'null') = a.value AND schoolid = 1) AS s1,
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE ifnull(string2, 'null') = a.value AND schoolid = 1) AS s2,
(SELECT count(*) FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1) AS total
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(string1, 'null') AS value FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(string2, 'null') AS value FROM school WHERE schoolid = 1) a
) b
```

Here's the updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6e26d/15/0)**.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You can get the basic counts as:

```
select value, sum(string1), sum(string2)
from ((select string1 as value, 1 as string1, 0 as string2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select string2 as value, 0 as string1, 1 as string2
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by value;
```

You can get the overall count by joining that in:

```
select value, sum(string1) / tt.cnt, sum(string2) / tt.cnt
from ((select string1 as value, 1 as string1, 0 as string2
       from t 
      ) union all
      (select string2 as value, 0 as string1, 1 as string2
       from t
      )
     ) t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from t) tt
group by value;
```

Note:  This calculates the "percentages" as ratios (which is how I like to see them).  You can format the results however you like.